# Ubuntu 20.04 serial interface problem. Corrupt characters, but not in windowz!

Tags: usb

USB Serial Problem: I have a 1500000 baud 8N1 serial that works perfectly on any Windows terminal I run, E.G. Putty, TeraTerm...but when I boot into any Ubuntu, I get garbage on any terminal I use, E.G. cutecom, kermit, picocom. With picocom, I have tested every baud rate, all 5,6,7,8 data sizes, odd even and none parity. I have also tried it on several other Linux machines and none of them work, but on windowz there is no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Your USB-to-serial adapter type may simply be unsupported by Linux. There are some that work properly only under Windows. If you want to use any external device under Linux, you should make sure it is compatible.

Comment: After 4 weeks of testing, that never occurred to me...but you were dead right, just tried a different type and it works. Thanks

Comment: Put it as a solution and I can accept it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your USB-to-serial adapter type may simply be unsupported by Linux. There are some that work properly only under Windows. If you want to use any external device under Linux, you should make sure it is compatible. –